# Angular auxiliary route is not appending `/` for only one of the configured routes?

Tags: angular

I have the following routes:

```
`const routes: Routes = [    
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'posts', pathMatch: 'full' },  
  { path: 'posts', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeView,  },
    { path: ':id/edit', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'modal' },
    { path: 'new', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'modal' } 
  ]},
  { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
];`
```

When user clicks to edit a post, the correct route is rendered `/posts/(modal:1/edit)`. However when user goes to click to create a new post, the path that Angular is trying to use to find a component is `/posts(modal:new)`. This is incorrect and is missing a forward slash after posts. Manually entering this into the URL `/posts/(modal:new)` renders the correct component.

This is how I am triggering the edit route:

```
`this.router.navigate([{outlets: {modal: `${this.post.postID}/edit`}}], {relativeTo: this.route});`
```

This is how I am triggering the new route:

```
`

this.router.navigate([{outlets: {modal: `new`}}], {relativeTo: this.route})

`
```

How can I fix the missing forward slash?

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, I think that the cause may be the sequence of the registered routes. Since it reaches the `:id/edit` first, it assumes that that's the case for the route entered.
Try using the below instead:

```
{ path: 'posts', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children: [
    { path: '', component: HomeView,  },
    { path: 'new', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'modal' }, 
    { path: ':id/edit', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'modal' }
  ]}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I had already tried that unfortunately. `NavigationError {id: 3, url: "/posts(modal:new)", error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'new'` same thing... Hmm i wonder if its a bug?

Comment: `this.router.navigateByUrl('posts/(modal:new)');  ` this did the trick. But I still would like to know why the above approach is not working.

Comment: Could you try `pathMatch: 'full'` and see if that works with the `new` route?

Comment: yeah same thing. `{ path: 'new', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, pathMatch: 'full', outlet: 'modal' }`  `this.router.navigate([{outlets: {modal: `new`}}], {relativeTo: this.route})` `NavigationError {id: 3, url: "/posts(modal:new)", error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'new'`

Comment: Can you try `this.router.navigate(['/posts/(modal:new)'])`? I believe when it comes to auxiliary routes, the navigation with parameters is overriding the prior possibility. Will have to dive into the source code :)

Comment: the following gives me the following error `ResolveEnd {id: 5, url: "/posts/%28modal:new%29", urlAfterRedirects: "/not-found", state: RouterStateSnapshot}`